# How do I store a refresh token for Google OAuth 2.0 to reauthenticate with Calendar API?

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0

**Product and context**

I have built a webapp using Python and Flask that authenticates with Google Calendar API and retrieves events.

**Error**

After a few days, however, I am given this error:

```
raise exceptions.RefreshError(
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: The credentials do not contain the necessary fields need to refresh the access token. You must specify refresh_token, token_uri, client_id, and client_secret.
```

**Assumed issue**

Presumably, this is because the access token has expired and the app is not refreshing it with the refresh token, but I'm keen to get clarification.

**Attempts to resolve**

1. I'm aware that the refresh token is only supplied on the first interaction with the authentication, so I have tried removing the access from the browser and deleting the cookies.
2. Explored online discussion around storing refresh tokens in a cookie

**Core question**

How do I store the refresh token, without a DB, and make use of it when the access token has expired.

**The Python Flask code**

```py
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import google.oauth2.credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from app import app

# Instantiates a client
client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
client.setup_logging()

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']


# Convert the credentials to a dictionary so it can be stored in the session
def credentials_to_dict(credentials):
        return {'token': credentials.token,
                'refresh_token': credentials.refresh_token,
                'token_uri': credentials.token_uri,
                'client_id': credentials.client_id,
                'client_secret': credentials.client_secret,
                'scopes': credentials.scopes}

# Build a config for authentication
CLIENT_CONFIG_JSON = {
        "web": {
            "client_id":  str(app.config['CLIENT_ID']),
            "project_id": "pto-planner",
            "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
            "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
            "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
            "client_secret": str(app.config['CLIENT_SECRET']),
            "redirect_uris": [
                str(app.config["REDIRECT_URI"])
            ]
        }
    }

REDIRECT_URI = app.config["REDIRECT_URI"]


@app.route('/')
def pto_plan():

    # Look for creds in session
    if 'credentials' in session:
        app.logger.info('Credentials in session')
        creds = Credentials(**session['credentials'])
        
        # If creds are not valid, work out why then reauthenticate
        if not creds.valid:
            app.logger.info('Credentials are in valid')
            if creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                app.logger.info('Credentials have expired')

                flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_config(
                    client_config = CLIENT_CONFIG_JSON,
                    scopes=SCOPES,
                    redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI)
                
                authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
                    access_type='offline',
                    include_granted_scopes='true')
                

                return redirect(authorization_url)
 
        else:
            app.logger.info('Credentials are valid')

            app.logger.info('Start the retrieval')
            service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

            # Interact with the calendar API
            events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='59190a8287d06c4662e1706eab23b0536a75f693bede44306fe40e3e1b713e69@group.calendar.google.com',
                                                timeMin=holiday_year_min,
                                                timeMax=holiday_year_max,
                                                singleEvents=True,
                                                orderBy='startTime').execute()
            events = events_result.get('items', [])

            // Load the application logic


    else:
        app.logger.info('Credentials are not in session')

        flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_config(
            client_config = CLIENT_CONFIG_JSON,
            scopes=SCOPES,
            redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI)
        
        
        # creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
            # Enable offline access so that you can refresh an access token without
            # re-prompting the user for permission. Recommended for web server apps.
            access_type='offline',
            # Enable incremental authorization. Recommended as a best practice.
            include_granted_scopes='true')
        
        session['state'] = state

        return redirect(authorization_url)

# The registered authentication route on Google Credentials
@app.route('/auth')
def auth():
    app.logger.info('Authorisation is progress')
    # CLIENT_CONFIG_JSON = app.config["CLIENT_CONFIG"]
    # REDIRECT_URI = app.config["REDIRECT_URI"]
    state = session['state']

    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_config(
            client_config = CLIENT_CONFIG_JSON,
            scopes=SCOPES,
            redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI,
            state=state)
    
    authorization_response = request.url

    code = request.args.get('code')
    
    flow.fetch_token(code=code)

    credentials = flow.credentials
    session['credentials'] = credentials_to_dict(credentials)

    app.logger.info('Authorisation complete')
    # return credentials_to_dict(credentials)
    return redirect('/')
```